# Order data by datetime Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.7

I have an array that contains data. I want to show my data by date (the new data at the head of the list) using the attribute "CreatedAt" which type is datetime.
here's my controller:

```
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $congesshows = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')
        ->findBy(array(),array('CreatedAt'=>'DESC'))
    ;

    $role = $user->getRoles() ;
    if($role[0]== "ROLE_ADMIN") {
        $congess = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')
            ->findBy( array('etat' => 'En cours'))
        ;
    }
    else {
        $congess = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')
            ->findBy(array('etat' => 'En attente'))
        ;
    }

    return $this->render(
        'appUserBundle:interne:please.html.twig',
        array('conges' => $congess,'congesshows'=>$congesshows)
   );
}
```

Comment: $congesshows includes all $congess records. What do you want to show?

Comment: I want to order them using the attribute CreatedAt. This one didn't work {  $congesshows = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')
        ->findBy(array(),array('CreatedAt'=>'DESC')) }

Comment: This sentence seems ok, for ordering. What version of doctrine do you use?

Comment: thansk guys this works !                                             if ($role[0] == "ROLE_ADMIN") {
            $congess = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')->findBy(array('etat' => 'En cours'), array('CreatedAt' => 'DESC'));


        } else {
            $congess = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')->findBy(array('etat' => 'En attente'), array('CreatedAt' => 'DESC'));

        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `$congesshows = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')
        ->createQueryBuilder(“c”)->orderBy(“CreatedAt”, 'DESC')->getQuery()->getResult()
    ;` ?

Comment: thansk guys this works ! if ($role[0] == "ROLE_ADMIN") { $congess = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')->findBy(array('etat' => 'En cours'), array('CreatedAt' => 'DESC')); } else { $congess = $em->getRepository('appUserBundle:Conges')->findBy(array('etat' => 'En attente'), array('CreatedAt' => 'DESC')); }